# Android: clipChildren=false and onClickListner for clipped children

Tags: android, onclick, transition

I have a problem.

We have layout custom frame layout with scaling and translating functionality

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
...
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    getChildAt(0).setTranslationX(vTranslate.x);
    getChildAt(0).setTranslationY(vTranslate.y);
    getChildAt(0).setScaleX(mScale.scaleFactor);
    getChildAt(0).setScaleY(mScale.scaleFactor);
}
```

The class listens for touch gestures and translations/scale its child.
I use it as parent viewgroup for my ViewGroup with content.

```
<MyFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gray"
android:clipChildren="false">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/calc_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"/>
```

Content for constraint layout adds programmaticaly and it is bigger then screen or parent group. Because of it we set clipChildren=false.
But the children which was out of bounds before transation don't response on onClick events.

Some pictures:

Start screen[image]

After translation:
[image]

The 6% node just doesn't answer to clicks.
Please, help me.

Add:
[image]

Comment: so what is the width of `MyFrameLayout` and `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: @pskink it is match_parent. If i set width like 2000dp for Constraint layout (white one) - the container will be bigger and clicks work. Dunno, why neither match_parent nor wrap_content works for Constraint layout. Its still has the "screen sizes"

Comment: so as you can see the events are passed down to child views if event (x, y) position is inside the parent - if it is outside the parent they are simply ignored - maybe instead of `setTranslation*` methods you could try `scrollTo` / `scrollBy` - i have no idea how it will work with `setScale*` thou...

Comment: @pskink Looks like it is constraint layout bug. It must wrap its content, but it doesn't

Comment: what bug? that `wrap_content` has the same meaning as `match_parent` ?

Comment: @pskink isn't it must wrap its content if its width = wrap_content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I couldn't find the way to make constraint layout(white one) to fit the content with wrap_content value. My workaround was to dynamicaly increase width and height of the constraint layout accordingly width and height of my node tree.

When you add additional node - layout measures grows and you see how it tweaks abit. Then to fix it i had to override onLayout() method in parent layout (It's green on the screenshots, but it was custom ZoomableLayout).

And now everything works fine. But i'm not sure if this implementation ugly or not.